# linux usb port monitoring

Tags: linux, bash, port, usb

I want a bash script to monitor USB ports of a linux server to detect when an external hard drive is plugged in and removed.

When a USB external drive is plugged in or removed, a text file is generated in some temp file about usb drive specs and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already have udev running on your system, and it is monitoring connect/disconnect events.  With the proper configuration it can trigger scripts to run, but it is primarily designed to create the device nodes.

On a Debian/Ubuntu system take a look at the existing rules in `/lib/udev/rules.d`, and /etc/udev/rules.d`.  See the **Run** section of the udev man page, for details about executing a task.

See:

- http://linux.die.net/man/8/udev
- http://linux.die.net/man/8/udevadm